# Checking a database for specific dates to prevent a booking cross over

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASPX web form where a logged-in user will be able to choose from a number of suit jacket sizes already stored in a database table. Once chosen the jacket size along with a from and to date for a booking the data is entered into a booking table with the relevant information.

I need help with code that will ensure that when another user chooses a suit jacket size they cannot use the same dates that are stored in the booking table for that size. The output would be in a label with an error message telling the user that the jacket size is unavailable for these dates.

I am using ASP.NET and the language VB for all of this work.

[image: SuitJacket table]

[image: booking table]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you showed us the code that you've tried and explained where it doesn't work we would be able to help you.

Comment: Hers some help: [ask] and some more is in the [tour] and there is also the [help]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with an If...Then statement check and a SQL query for the lookup.

```
Dim mySqlConnection As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim reader As SqlDataReader

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [ID] FROM [Table] WHERE (JacketSize = @jacketSize AND (DateFrom <= @dateWanted AND DateTo >= @dateWanted))"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.Connection = mySqlConnection
cmd.Parameters.Add("@jacketSize", 'JacketSize field')
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dateWanted", 'DateWanted field')
mySqlConnection.Open()
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

If (reader.HasRows = TRUE) Then
    'code to execute if date is taken'
Else
    'code to execute if date is not taken'
End If

mySqlConnection.Close()
```

Edit: Forgot to add the parameters. Thanks Andrew Morton.